# androidXのCameraControlを使用して、カメラの露光補正値を変更したいです。

Tags: java, android, kotlin

現在、以下のプログラムでandroidの端末のカメラを起動するプログラムを作成しています。

```
package com.example.mycameraxapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.File
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import androidx.camera.core.CameraControl

typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Set up the listener for take photo button
        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {}

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
                }
            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview)
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }
            
            // 露光補正値設定
            var cameraexposure = Camera.CameraControl()
                cameraexposure.setExposureCompensationIndex(30)
            
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
        IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) { //リクエストコードが正しいか確認
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) { //カメラへのアクセス権限がある場合はカメラを起動
                startCamera()
            } else { //権限がなければトーストを提示して権限がないことを通知
                Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

カメラの起動自体はできたので、次にプレビュー画面の露光補正値を変更しようと思い、公式ドキュメントを元に作成しているのですが、公式に記載された内容をどのように実装したら良いか分からず困っています。

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl?hl=ja#setExposureCompensationIndex(kotlin.Int)

こちらのサイトの「setExposureCompensationIndex」を使用して値を変更しようとしています。
上記のコードでもあるように、setExposureCompensationIndexをメソッドに持つ「CameraControl」インターフェースをインポートしています。

```
import androidx.camera.core.CameraControl
```

そして、メソッドを使用するために以下の記述をしているのですが、CameraControlの部分が「Rename Reference」と赤字になってしまいうまくいきません。

```
// 露光補正値設定
var cameraexposure = Camera.CameraControl()
    cameraexposure.setExposureCompensationIndex(30)
```

公式ドキュメントを見ても詳しい実装の方法が分からず困っています。

Answer (score 0):

cameraに対して操作する時は、ライフサイクルに関連付けたインスタンスを操作する必要があります。

```
val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview)
```

露出補正を設定する場合は、先にサポートしているかを確認します。

```
val exposureState = camera.cameraInfo.exposureState
if(exposureState.isExposureCompensationSupported) { ... }
```

端末のカメラがそれをサポートしている場合、露出補正値を設定します。
ここでは露出補正が30を例にしていますが、Rangeの範囲内を指定してください。
これは端末ごとに異なる可能性があります。

```
if(exposureState.isExposureCompensationSupported) {
    val range = exposureState.exposureCompensationRange

    if(range.contains(30)) {
        camera.cameraControl.setExposureCompensationIndex(30)
    }
}
```

cameraxのversionが 1.0系だと、露出補正は実験的APIのためのエラーが出る可能性があります。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます！
いただいた情報を組み込みましたが、デバイスが対応していないのかキャプチャーに影響は見られませんでした。
そのため、別の方法として「CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME」を使用するやり方も調査してみました。
https://qiita.com/ohwada/items/10fa71120cf4b9e793c3
こちらの内容をもとに試しているのですが、
`CaptureRequest.Builder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, 10)`
上記のコードで値を変更しようとしているのですが、「set」の部分で「java.lang.reflect.Array.set?(multiple choises...)」とエラーが出てしまっています。

Comment: なるほどです。ご確認いただきたいのですが、
isExposureCompensationSupportedの戻り値はTrueでしたでしょうか？
range.contains(30)はTrueでしたでしょうか？

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。いえ、確認したところいずれの戻り値もfalseになっておりました。そのため、やはり対応していないことが考えられます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ハードウェア的に対応していない可能性が高いです。サポートしている別端末をご使用ください。

Comment: 承知しました。ありがとうございます！